# C unable to store into an array

Tags: c, arrays

```
printf("\n\tHow many integers: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    iPtr = (int*) malloc(num * sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("Enter integer # %d ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", (iPtr + i));

        temp = *(iPtr + i);
        while(temp != 0) {

            if(i == temp % 10) {
                ary[i]++;
            }
            temp /= 10;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(ary[i] > 0) {
            printf("digit %d : %d\n", i, ary[i]);
        }
    }
```

I am writing a program to store the occurrences of an digit from an integers,but when I run the program, I see the array is not working

so I want to ask why it is not allow me to store the digit from an integer?
and how to fix it?

and 1 more question, what is the different between if(x = y) and if(x == y)

Comment: This is not C#, it is C.

Comment: Please ask only one question by question, and clarify what is “not working”. What did you expect? What did you observe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you've almost got it right but I think the biggest issue is your array has garbage in it to begin with (when declared).

```
 int i, temp, num, *iPtr;
int ary[10] = {0};            //I can only assume you did *not* do this

//printf("\n\tHow many integers: ");
//scanf("%d", &num);
num = 2;

iPtr = malloc(num * sizeof(int));



for(i = 0; i < num; i++) 
{
    printf("Enter integer # %d ", i+1);
    scanf("%d", (iPtr +1));

    temp = *(iPtr+1);
    while(temp != 0) 
    {

        if( (i) == temp % 10)     
        {
            ary[i]++;             
        }

        temp /= 10;
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    if(ary[i] > 0) 
    {
        printf("digit %d : %d\n", i, ary[i]);
    }
}
```

This program is also incomplete, because your loop might end before you've even checked a digit high enough to match. Ie, you're checking if temp still has a number in it, but you're only comparing it to **i**, which doesn't change (so if the digit in temp is 9, but i is 1, you'll never trigger to see that there's a 9 to count).

So I modified

```
if( (i) == temp % 10)     
{
    ary[i]++;             
}
```

to

```
        for (int zz = 0; zz < 10; zz++)
        {
            if( (zz) == temp % 10) 
            {
               ary[zz]++;            
            }
        }
```

And now the program counts all the digits. 
Output:[image]

This is all assuming I'm even understanding your program right. And usually I don't like straight posting code but I really didn't know how else to get the point across. Tired atm. :/

Comment: wow, I tried it, and it is work :D, so my logic was wrong, aww, well thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Your problem is this line:</strike>

```
if(i == temp % 10)
```

Due to [operator precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm), == is evaluated before %. Fix by surrounding the % with brackets:

```
if(i == (temp % 10))
```

Also, to answer your other question as well as a few nitpicks (apologies beforehand):

- = is assignment, == is equality testing.
- It looks like your inner while loop may be misusing i, according to what you've said you're trying to do.

Comment: I tried if(i == (temp % 10)), but it still not allow me to store

,the loop at the last will print all ary elements which have value, but there are nothing printed

Comment: Unless I'm reading wrong, your operator precedence link lists modulus [%] above [==]. I just tested that particular comparison and it works as expected. Your recommendation does not seem correct.

Comment: @Alex you're right; I think the real mistake might be using i incorrectly.

Comment: @CongXu The precedence specified here is incorrect .                int temp=4;
    if(1 == temp%3)
        printf("true");
    
    if(1 == (temp%3))
        printf("true");                                                      will both return true .

Answer (score 1):

The following loop needs re-consideration

```
while(temp != 0) {

            if(i == temp % 10) {
                ary[i]++;
            }
            temp /= 10;
        }
```

I am not sure what you are trying here .

FIrst think over `if(i == temp % 10)`

you are doing too many things here . Here i is being compared with the 10 modulus temp and in case they are equal you proceed to store them into the array .

So suppose you just started executing this loop . So i = 0 . Suppose the first number you enter is say 1023 . So

```
i = 0
temp = 1023
```

Now 1023%10 would give you 3 .

Hence your if loop becomes `if(0 == 3 )` // Its an equality check . Whether 0 is equal to 3 or not .

Obviously this will be false and hence you inner array loop is never executed .

Comment: but I am using while loop, so it would divided by 10 and do the compare again until temp is not 0

Comment: Rex is correct. He's doing a mod 10 to do decimal shifting. He'll compare 1023%10 = 3, then 102%10 = 2, then 10%10 = 0 (bingo! digit found), then 1%10 = 1. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

if(x=y) -> This is an assignment operator. i.e you are assigning value of y to x. This will always assign y to x and execute the statements within it.

if(x==y) -> This is a comparator operator. Here you are comparing if value of x is equal to y. If true, it will execute the statements within {} otherwise it wont.